# iPad Wi-Fi connection issues, including showing as connected with Wi-Fi disabled

Tags: ipad, wifi, crash, ios

I've got a fairly new iPad, running iOS 10.3, which is doing some very odd things with Wi-Fi. Specifically, having issues with deciding it's properly connected to Wi-Fi.

Sometimes, when I go into the Wi-Fi settings, it simultaneously shows the iPad as being connected to Wi-Fi whilst the Wi-Fi is disabled:

[image: Wi-Fi both on and off]

Other times, it can go one better, and show Wi-Fi disabled + no signal + full signal:

[image: Wi-Fi on and off and no signal]

Another trick is to show Wi-Fi as on and connected whilst off in the menu:

[image: Wi-Fi on and off]

Fairly often, when connecting to a Wi-Fi network, I seem to have to disable Wi-Fi + wait 4 seconds + enable Wi-Fi to have it decide that there's a valid connection. If I'm unlucky, the Settings app will crash during me doing this…

I'd rather not upgrade to iOS 11 just yet, as a few apps I use haven't got iOS 11 versions out yet.

Short of an upgrade, is there anything I can do to my iPad to fix its frequent confusions about if it is connected to Wi-Fi / disconnected, has Wi-Fi enabled / has Wi-Fi disabled?

Comment: Have you tried to reset your network connections?

Comment: @fsb Not yet, partly due to not wanting to have to re-enter lots of network passwords...

Comment: That's the only thing I've found that might fix situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a factory restore to your iPad.

Yes that does automatically update your iPad to iOS 11 but you can update to the lates iOS 10 update as well. The issue you have here is related to the software (and sometimes the connection with your other devices like an iPhone).

Use http://ipsw.me/# as your source for iOS 10 updates for the iPad. Make sure that you backup your iPad if possible (iCloud Backup or iTunes) then download the file you need (choose it based on your exact device) and then save it. Go to iTunes and where it has restore iPad, press and hold on to the "Option" key on Mac (ALT on Windows) and click on restore. That should let you select the update file where you saved it and then use it to restore your iPad.

If you need any assistance let me know.