# How to actually forget all past Wifi networks on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

Based on the [advice given on my last question on iOS and Wifi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/303386/ipad-wi-fi-connection-issues-including-showing-as-connected-with-wi-fi-disabled), I want to make my iPad forget all the wifi networks it has ever connected to. My problem is, how to actually do it?

I've gone to General, Reset then Reset Network Settings, then done a reset. That prompts for an unlock code, then spends a bit of time with the Apple  logo showing, then restarts the ipad.

After this network, the iPad has:

- Forgotten the passwords to all protected Wifi networks
- Forgotten which Wifi networks I have told it "Don't auto-connect" and "Dont auto-login"

What the iPad has failed to do is:

- Forget all Wifi networks it has ever connected to

After the restart, the iPad immediately starts trying to connect to a paid-for wifi hotspot that's in range that I had previously set to "Don't auto-connect", and promptly pops up a capture login page for that network!

So, how do I make my iPad actually forget all networks ever, so that after a reset it doesn't know any networks, and won't try to connect to anything it has ever used before?

Answer (score 1):

You might have iCloud keychain turned on. Keychain saves Wifi passwords.
Try looking for it in Keychain access or just turn off keychain to prevent automatically accessing it.

Comment: After the reset, it has forgotten all wifi passwords, and prompts me to enter them again before connecting. However, it still auto-connects to non-protected wifis it connected to before!